# How to get nearby place in android when getting mylocation by lat and long

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working on application where i get MyLocation by Latitude and Longitude .Now I want to get the Users who is in 5 Km within my range .I am using following code to get the Lat and Long of User.

```
  if(gps.canGetLocation()){

     getlatitude = gps.getLatitude();
     getlongitude = gps.getLongitude();
     latitude_mString = String.valueOf(getlatitude);
     longitude_mString = String.valueOf(getlongitude);
     Log.d("Value of lat and long",  latitude_mString+""+longitude_mString);
     Log.d("u r", "ur in register lati loni");
        new Thread(null,latlongThread,"").start();
    }
     }else{

    gps.showSettingsAlert();
}
 marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(getlatitude, getlongitude)).title("Me");

//marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.));

    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(getlatitude, getlongitude))
            .zoom(12).build();

       googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

    googleMap.addMarker(marker);
 return rootView;
}
```

By This Code i can get mylocation .I am storing each user  data in my API .So i have all data regarding lat and long of each user .So now i want to print user who have location or lat and long within 5 km of me.

Answer (score 0):

Use the location's distanceTo method

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo(android.location.Location)

Comment: These are only methods define ..there is no exp for implementation of it .

Comment: Why don't you do a Google search for android+distanceTo+example ? I can't be bothered to do hand holding.